# hadoop MapReduce exception with multiple nodes

Tags: hadoop

I include a self-contained sequence of commands that lead to the issue. I have a work-in-progress Cluster configuration. It is also worth noting that this same example worked fine when I didn't have all the resource and history managers configured in `yarn-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml`.

The problem `Cannot create directory /user/deploy/QuasiMonteCarlo_1391523248477_997612342/in` appears to be a wrong file path prefix somewhere because the relevant user directories are:

- `/home/deploy/`
- `/home/deploy/hdfs`
- `/home/deploy/hdfs/name`
- `/home/deploy/hdfs/data`

So how come it tries accessing `/user/deploy` ?

```
deploy@olympus:~$ start-all.sh 
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [olympus]
olympus: starting namenode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-namenode-olympus.out
hera: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-hera.out
olympus: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-olympus.out
zeus: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-zeus.out
poseidon: starting datanode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-datanode-poseidon.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/hadoop-deploy-secondarynamenode-olympus.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-resourcemanager-olympus.out
olympus: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-olympus.out
zeus: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-zeus.out
hera: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-hera.out
poseidon: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/dev/hadoop/2.2.0/logs/yarn-deploy-nodemanager-poseidon.out
deploy@olympus:~$ hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi 2 5
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 5
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot create directory /user/deploy/QuasiMonteCarlo_1391523248477_997612342/in. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 5 has reached the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 5. The number of live datanodes 4 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 4 seconds.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:59598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$16.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:806)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Comment: I think you are running job even before namenode is out of safemode, can you start job after few mins of starting namenode? Also what is value of dfs.dir.data in hdfs-site.xml

Comment: @rVr Indeed I think this is the reason.

Comment: Cool, I've posted the same as answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Job is being kicked off before namenode is out of safemode after startup. Starting job after namenode leaves safemode will fix the issue.

Answer (score 12):

you can try below command.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because Namenode enters into safemode
[How to leave](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html)